# What's the difference between 'type' and 'callType' in parity trace?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, transaction-trace

For the parity node, the response for getting the transaction trace contain `"callType"` and `"type"` which are all `"call"`. But for geth node we only get `'type':'Call'`. So I am confused, whats the difference between `"callType"` and `"type"`?

https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x626590b434e06b79fdd2187b28a55569f6c0636c6806808beb6ce2c743e88188&type=parity#raw

```
 ...
 "action": {
  "callType": "call",
  "from": "0x8871759b2530fee82cd1b31c534252a1db707b0b",
  "gas": "0x25ce48",
  "input": "0x3dea52fc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000077e772392b600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  "to": "0x94c0d029a7b64bf443e89c5006089364c0d60d61",
  "value": "0x0"
},
"blockHash": "0xbe847be2bceb74e660daf96b3f0669d58f59dc9101715689a00ef864a5408f43",
"blockNumber": 6000000,
"result": {
  "gasUsed": "0x2532ed",
  "output": "0x"
},
"subtraces": 1,
"traceAddress": [],
"transactionHash": "0x626590b434e06b79fdd2187b28a55569f6c0636c6806808beb6ce2c743e88188",
"transactionPosition": 45,
"type": "call"},
```

...

but for geth node, I got:

```
  ...
  'result': {'type': 'CALL',
  'from': '0x8871759b2530fee82cd1b31c534252a1db707b0b',
  'to': '0x94c0d029a7b64bf443e89c5006089364c0d60d61',
  'value': '0x0',
  'gas': '0x25ce48',
  'gasUsed': '0x2532ed',
  'input': 
 '0x3dea52fc00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e800000000 
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000077e772392b600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
  'output': '0x',
  'time': '10.824367485s',
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an answer to this question we can look at the [source code for Parity-Ethereum](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/rpc/src/v1/types/trace.rs) and the [documentation for the `trace` module](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-trace-module).

There are two distinct definitions in the source:

**Action**

```
/// Action
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Action {
    /// Call
    Call(Call),
    /// Create
    Create(Create),
    /// Suicide
    Suicide(Suicide),
    /// Reward
    Reward(Reward),
}
```

**CallType**

```
/// Call type.
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "lowercase")]
pub enum CallType {
    /// None
    None,
    /// Call
    Call,
    /// Call code
    CallCode,
    /// Delegate call
    DelegateCall,
    /// Static call
    StaticCall,
}
```

So here we can see that every trace has an `Action` (represented by `type` in the JSON), and if the `Action` is a `Call`, then it can have a `CallType` (represented by `calltype`).

These are all generally represented by the [Ethereum OpCodes](https://github.com/trailofbits/evm-opcodes):

**Calls**

```
0xf1    CALL    Message-call into an account    -   Complicated
0xf2    CALLCODE    Message-call into this account with alternative account's code  -   Complicated
0xf4    DELEGATECALL    Message-call into this account with an alternative account's code, but persisting into this account with an alternative account's code  -   Complicated
0xfa    STATICCALL  Similar to CALL, but does not modify state  -   40
```

**Other**

```
0xf0    CREATE  Create a new account with associated code   -   32000
0xff    SELFDESTRUCT    Halt execution and register account for later deletion  -   5000*
```

Not very sure about `Reward`, but here suggests it is for [uncle and mining rewards](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/8526).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I know this is out of scope, but I wonder what's the difference between `Action` and `Calls` and how can I generate the same result in geth node?

Comment: What do you mean? A transaction will be the same whether processed by Parity or Geth. The resulting trace json is just a specific implementation of that client. Maybe I misunderstand your goal, are you trying to achieve something specific?

Comment: My goal is to get the same trace json schema using geth node, as I only have geth node. Then validate the result against parity trace(on etherscan). I have managed to get all the informations except for the trace `Action` type. In geth node there is only 5 trace call types: `CREATE` `CALL` `CALLCODE` `DELEGATECALL ` `SELFDESTRUCT ` ([source code for geth call_tracer](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/461291882edce0ac4a28f64c4e8725b7f57cbeae/eth/tracers/internal/tracers/call_tracer.js)). It doesn't seem to match `Action` type or `Calls` type in parity trace json.

Comment: I see references to `STATICCALL` [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/461291882edce0ac4a28f64c4e8725b7f57cbeae/eth/tracers/internal/tracers/call_tracer.js#L68), so the only thing missing is `Reward`, which if you look at the post I linked to at the end, mentions it isn't even publicly used yet. So it does look like you have a one to one mapping here.